# Google Calendar Events insert not honoring eventType

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I cannot create a "focus time" event using the "try this method" page [here](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/insert?apix_params=%7B%22calendarId%22%3A%22primary%22%2C%22resource%22%3A%7B%22end%22%3A%7B%22dateTime%22%3A%222023-02-07T15%3A00%3A00-00%3A00%22%7D%2C%22start%22%3A%7B%22dateTime%22%3A%222023-02-07T13%3A00%3A00-00%3A00%22%7D%2C%22eventType%22%3A%22focusTime%22%2C%22summary%22%3A%22Focus%20Event%20Not%20Working%22%7D%7D).

I have "eventType": "focusTime" but the returned JSON has this (and the calendar shows a regular event was created):

```
"eventType": "default"
```

Am I doing something wrong?  The API clearly says this is supported.

Thanks

Comment: What is this link for?  I am talking about using Apps Script API.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the [Events documentation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events), the `eventType` parameter, is a read-only parameter.

> eventType - Specific type of the event. Read-only. Possible values are:
> "default" - A regular event or not further specified.
> "outOfOffice" - An out-of-office event.
> **"focusTime" - A focus-time event.**

There is already a feature request for this in Google's Issue Tracker. You can vote for the request through [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/206630110).